# How to integrate the following? $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^{\alpha+1}}\,dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

> $$2\alpha\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1-\cos{x}}{x^{\alpha+1}}dx=?$$

I know that it should be solved by integrating on a contour of two semicircles with radius $\epsilon$ and $T$, and the real line. Then as $\epsilon\to0$ and $T\to\infty$ it should be the value of residue. How can I calculate the residue?

Note: I checked with wolframalpha, and it should be $$-\cos\left(\frac{\pi\alpha}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(-\alpha\right).$$

Comment: You need to decide of what function you should compute the residue. Did you?

Comment: I think that it should be $\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x^{\alpha+1}}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $I(\alpha)$ be the integral

$$I(\alpha)=2\alpha\int_0^\infty \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^{1+\alpha}}\,dx \tag 1$$

for $0<\alpha<2$.  Integrating $(1)$ by parts with $u=1-\cos(x)$ and $v=-\frac{1}{\alpha x^{\alpha}}$ reveals

$$I(\alpha)=2\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x^\alpha}\,dx \tag 2$$

Now, moving to the complex plane, we analyze the closed contour integral

$$J(\alpha)=\oint_C \frac{e^{iz}}{z^\alpha}\,dz \tag 3$$

where $C$ is comprised of (i) the segment on the real line from $\epsilon$ to $R$, (ii) the quarter circle with radius $R$, centered at the origin, from $R$ to $iR$, (iii) the line segment along the imaginary axis from $iR$ to $i\epsilon$, and (iv) the quarter circle with radius $\epsilon$, centered at the origin, from $i\epsilon$ to $\epsilon$.

With the branch cut chosen as the line along the non-positive real axis, from $0$ to $-\infty$, the integrand in $3$ is analytic in and on $C$.  Then, Cauchy's Integral Theorem guarantees that $J(\alpha)=0$.  Therefore, we have for $R>\varepsilon>0$

$$\begin{align}
0&=\int_\varepsilon^R \frac{e^{ix}}{x^\alpha}\,dx+iR^{1-\alpha}\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{iR e^{i\phi}}e^{i(1-\alpha)\phi}\,d\phi \\\\&
-e^{i(1-\alpha) \pi/2}\int_\varepsilon^R \frac{e^{-y}}{y^\alpha}\,dy-i\varepsilon^{1-\alpha}\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{i\varepsilon e^{i\phi}}e^{i(1-\alpha)\phi}\,d\phi\tag4
\end{align}$$

In the limit as $R\to \infty$ the contribution to $J(\alpha)$ from the integration along the quarter circle with radius $R$ vanishes.  Hence, we find from $(4)$ that

$$\begin{align}
0&=\int_\varepsilon^\infty \frac{e^{ix}}{x^\alpha}\,dx -e^{i(1-\alpha) \pi/2}\int_\varepsilon^\infty \frac{e^{-y}}{y^\alpha}\,dy-i\varepsilon^{1-\alpha}\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{i\varepsilon e^{i\phi}}e^{i(1-\alpha)\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&=\int_\varepsilon^\infty \frac{e^{ix}}{x^\alpha}\,dx-\frac{e^{i(1-\alpha) \pi/2}}{1-\alpha}\int_\varepsilon^\infty \frac{e^{-y}}{y^{\alpha-1}}\,dy \\\\
&+\frac{e^{i(1-\alpha) \pi/2}e^{-\varepsilon}\varepsilon^{1-\alpha}}{1-\alpha}-i\varepsilon^{1-\alpha}\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{i\varepsilon e^{i\phi}}e^{i(1-\alpha)\phi}\,d\phi\tag5
\end{align}$$

Taking the imaginary part of $(5)$ and letting $\varepsilon\to 0^+$ yields

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x^\alpha}\,dx&=\frac{\cos(\pi\alpha/2)}{1-\alpha}\Gamma(2-\alpha)\\\\
&=\cos(\alpha \pi/2)\Gamma(1-\alpha)\\\\
&=-\alpha \cos(\alpha \pi/2)\Gamma(-\alpha)\tag6
\end{align}$$

where we applied twice in succession the functional equation $\Gamma (1+x)=x\Gamma(x)$ to arrive at $(6)$.  Finally, we have

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{2\alpha \int_0^\infty \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^{1+\alpha}}\,dx=-2\alpha \cos(\alpha \pi/2)\Gamma(-\alpha)}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Integrate on the quarter circle $\epsilon\to i\epsilon$. The imaginary part of this integral is precisely: $$-i\epsilon^{1-\alpha}\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-\epsilon\cdot\sin(t)}\cos(\epsilon\cdot\cos(t)-\alpha\cdot t)\,\mathrm{d}t$$Which seems to diverge as $\epsilon\to0^+$. Certainly, the usual $\sin t>\frac{2}{\pi}t$ trick fails here. How did you conclude that this quantity vanishes?

Comment: To be more clear, I can show this vanishes if $0<\Re\alpha<1$, but I think $\Re\alpha\in[1,2)$ is a stretch.

Comment: @FShrike On the quarter circle $z=\varepsilon e^{i\phi}$, $\phi \in [0,\pi/4]$, we have $$ \text{Im}\left(e^{i z }\right)=\sin( \varepsilon \cos(\phi)) e^{- \varepsilon \sin(\phi)}$$which is $O(\varepsilon)$.

Comment: The imaginary part of the complex integrand and the imaginary part of the integral aren’t the same. Be that as it may, when $1<\Re\alpha<2$, the integral (even when considered in real and imaginary parts) numerically diverges and I see no analytic reason to believe otherwise. For, we divide by $z^\alpha$, and I believe you have neglected the corresponding $e^{-\alpha it}$ (which changes $\sin(\epsilon…)$ to some other, non-vanishing, term). Anyway, analytic continuation means it is perfectly fine to use your method for $0<\alpha<1$ and extend to $0<\alpha<2$.

Comment: (Forgive me if I’m mistaken, I just really don’t believe this particular integral vanishes)

Comment: @FShrike I've edited to address your comments.

Comment: Thanks. What I claimed to diverge does diverge, but, I missed the trick with the integration by parts. Now I agree, in total, that the sum of imaginary error terms vanishes for $1<\alpha<2$.

Comment: @FShrike Indeed.  Note that the case $\alpha =1$ needs special care.

Answer (score 7):

We have:
$$ I(\alpha) = 2\alpha\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^{\alpha+1}}\,dx  \stackrel{IBP}{=} 2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x^{\alpha}}\,dx$$
but since $\mathcal{L}(\sin x) = \frac{1}{1+s^2}$ and $\mathcal{L}^{-1}(x^{-\alpha})=\frac{s^{\alpha-1}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}$ we also have:
$$ I(\alpha) = \frac{2}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{s^{\alpha-1}}{s^2+1}\,ds $$
and the last integral is a value of the Euler beta function.

By the reflection formula for the $\Gamma$ function the claim follows.